# Yii custom ordering and sorting posts

Tags: php, yii, dataprovider

I'm building a website using yii framework and i have two models say Post and User.and the user model stores the preferences of the user.currently the posts are being decalre in no order as such,how do i order the posts differently for each user depending on their preferences.i want to order all posts for each user like its done on facebook.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'order'=>'likes DSC', 
        ));
            $total = Post::model()->count();
            $pages = new CPagination($total);
            $pages->pageSize = 10;
            $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
            $posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `DESC`, not `DSC` :

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'order'=>'likes DSC',
        ));
```

Comment: @lireza Fallah. Correct comment, but your provided code is still incorrect.